# how can i load 3d model and get point's model?

Tags: java, processing

I have a model I want to Load and cut it into triangles so how can I do this?
And access to the points of the model

I tried to upload and display the model using this code :

```java
PShape flower;

void setup() {
    size(1000, 600, P3D);

    flower = loadShape("Flower.obj");
}

void draw() {

    shape(flower);
}
```

but i have this message :The file "Flower.obj" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
java.lang.NullPointerException

Note :I have uploaded the model with obj suffix via this link :
https://www.artec3d.com/3d-models/science-and-education

Comment: Does Flower.obj exist and in the right place?  The error says ""Flower.obj" is missing or inaccessible"

Comment: Also, you might want to try http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yes i write the right place but  still this error